# Auto-mount partitions upon wake up

Tags: mount, linux-mint

I am running Linux Mint 11 Katya. Whenever the system is awakened after hibernating, my Windows partitions do not automatically show on the desktop. I have to click on Computer, select one or more of my Windows partitions by double-clicking on them and then it appears my partitions become mounted because my folder links work again and I can see both partitions on my desktop. Is there any way to auto-mount these upon coming back from hibernate?

**EDIT**

This is my /etc/fstab file

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=45413e15-c59d-4bde-b3c0-70aac7ca8202 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=b231787d-49ad-4e6f-a038-558391312f68 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Sounds like you are using autofs, how are your partitions mounted? Please post the contents of `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: @terdon: See update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, your problem is that you have not set your windows partitions to be mounted automatically. To do so, each of them will need an entry in `/etc/fstab`, the file where partition mounting settings are kept :

1. `fstab` can use either the UUID or the device name of a partition, I will use the `/dev/sdxN` names because it is easier to explain that way. The first step is finding out what the device name of each of your windows partitions is. The easiest way would be to mount each of them manually as you describe in your question, then open a terminal and run this command:

   ```
   mount
   ```

   That will list the currently mounted partitions in the format of `/dev/sdxN on /mountpoint`. Identify your windows partitions.
2. Add the relevant lines to `/etc/fstab` (for this example, I am assuming the partitions in question are `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2`, replace these with whatever your partitions are called).

   ```
   /dev/sda1   /media/windws1  ntfs    defaults    0   0
   /dev/sda2   /media/windows2 ntfs    defaults    0   0
   ```

That's it! You can check that everything works ok by running `sudo mount -a`. They should now be mounted automatically next time you reboot.

Comment: Perfect! I will try this later and report back. This is for a home PC and I am work. Thank you.

Comment: Seems to work.. going to test more over the next few days. Thanks again!